# Exercise 7(c), Section 31 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, compactness, perfect-map

> Let $p \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a closed continuous surjective map such that $p^{-1} \big( \{ y \} \big)$ is compact for each $y \in Y$. (Such a map is called a *perfect map*.) (c) Show that if $X$ is locally compact, then so is $Y$.

**My attempt:** Let $y\in Y$. $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact. Since $X$ is locally compact, we have $\forall x\in p^{-1}(y)$, $\exists C_x\subseteq X$, $\exists U_x \in \mathcal{N}_x$ such that $U_x \subseteq C_x$ and $C_x$ is compact. So $\{U_x |x\in p^{-1}(y)\}$ is an open cover of $p^{-1}(y)$. Since $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact, $\exists \{U_{x_1},..,U_{x_n}\}$ finite subcover of $\{U_x |x\in p^{-1}(y)\}$. $p^{-1}(y)\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{x_i}=U$. By exercise 3 section 26, $C=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_{x_i}$ is compact. $U\subseteq C$. So $p(U)\subseteq p(C)$. Since $p$ is continuous, $p(C)$ is compact. By [generalize hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4450307/861687)/chapter 3 theorem 11.2 of Dugundji topology, $\exists V\in \mathcal{N}_y$ such that $p^{-1}(V)\subseteq U$. Since $p$ is surjective, $V=p(p^{-1}(V))\subseteq p(U)$. Thus $V\subseteq p(U)\subseteq p(C)$. Hence $\exists p(C)\subseteq Y$,  $\exists V\in \mathcal{N}_y$ such that $V \subseteq p(C)$ and $p(C)$ is compact. **Is this proof correct?**

**Edit:** Unlike [exercise 7(a)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452715/861687) and [exercise 7(b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452805/861687), in this proof we used all conditions of perfect map.

Comment: It is correct so long as you justify the existence of $V$, which you seem to have done

Comment: @FShrike I saw your academia post. You have learned so many things by your own. Which is fascinating. I want to ask, how long you have been doing pure math? And from which book did you study topology?

Comment: Thank you. I have always been "good at" maths, but have only actively tried to study maths in a serious way for a year and a half. You know, I just cruised earlier in school, wasn't particularly interested.

Comment: Most of my knowledge of topology comes from MSE and Royden's real analysis, 4th edition

Comment: It is probably more appropriate to move this to a private chatroom or a less public comments section, but I don't have a clear study pattern since finding resources a self-studier is quite hard... I just learn from what resources I can get, usually lecture-note pdfs