# Prob 12, Sec 26 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Why we need continuity to show the result?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $f: X\mapsto Y$ be a closed continuous surjective map such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact, for each $y\in Y$. Show that if $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact.

My question is why do we need $f$ to be continuous? It seems I can prove this result without continuity.

Here is my proof:

> Let $\left\{ U_{\alpha}:\alpha\in J\right\} $ be an open covering
>   of $X$. Since $f$ is surjective and $f^{-1}\left(y\right)$ is compact,
>   for any $y\in Y$, there exists a finite set $J_{y}\subset J$ such
>   that $\left\{ U_{\alpha}:\alpha\in J_{y}\right\} $ is an open covering
>   of $f^{-1}\left(y\right)$. Suppose we can find a finite set $\tilde{Y}\subset Y$,
>   such that $\left\{ U_{\alpha}:\ \alpha\in\cup_{y\in\tilde{Y}}J_{y}\right\} $
>   covers $X$, then we are done.
>
> For any $y\in Y$, $\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}$ is an open
>   set in $X$. Hence, $X-\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}$ is closed.
>   Since $f$ is a closed mapping, we know $Y-f\left(X-\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}\right)$
>   is open. Since $y\in Y-f\left(X-\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}\right)$,
>   there exists a neightbourhood $V_{y}$ of $y$, such that $V_{y}\subset Y-f\left(X-\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}\right)$.
>   In other words, $f^{-1}\left(V_{y}\right)\subset\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}$.
>   Since $Y$ is compact, there exists a finite set $\tilde{Y}$ such
>   that $Y\subset\cup_{y\in\tilde{Y}}V_{y}$. Therefore, 
>   $$
> X=f^{-1}\left(Y\right)\subset f^{-1}\left(\cup_{y\in\tilde{Y}}V_{y}\right)=\cup_{y\in\tilde{Y}}f^{-1}\left(V_{y}\right)\subset\cup_{y\in\tilde{Y}}\left(\cup_{\alpha\in J_{y}}U_{\alpha}\right)=\cup_{\alpha\in J'}U_{\alpha}
> $$
>   where $J'=\cup_{y\in\tilde{Y}}J_{y}$ is a finite set.  Q.E.D.

[I've read an earlier post ([Prob 12, Sec 26 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to show that the domain of a perfect map is compact if its range is compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291151/prob-12-sec-26-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-how-to-show-that-the-domain-of-a-p)) and the proof therein, but I still cannot get a clue. As a new commer, I cannot leave a comment there.]

Comment: It seems that your proof is correct, so that continuity of $f$ is not needed. Just a comment: You actually do not need the set $V_y$; you can just take $V_y := Y - f(X - \bigcup_{\alpha \in J_y} U_\alpha)$.

Comment: Hi, PhoemueX. Thanks for checking it for me.

Comment: @Lixie can you please have a look at my post now? I've just edited my post to include a write-up of the proof based on the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you're right. I think your proof is valid and continuity is not needed for this proof of Munkres Problem number 12 in section 26 *Connectedness and Compactness*.

> In fact, this was already discussed by some other people.
>
> - A nice presentation of a proof already arguing that **continuity is not necessary** for a proof is given by *Vadim@dbFin* at *[Munkres: Section 26](http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/?t=problem-12-solution)*
> - You already pointed to this related *[MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291151)*  in your question.
> - There is another *[MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902472)* presenting a proof of the problem and  also asking if continuity is needed. @DanielFischer also provided  a clear answer to this question.

*Note:* Let's have a look at the precise formulation of the problem. In my version of *[Munkres Topology (edition 2)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004DX5K5K)* it is stated as

> **12.** Let $\rho:X\rightarrow Y$ be a closed continuous surjective map such that $\rho^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact, for each $y\in Y$. (Such a map is called a **perfect map**.) Show that if $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact.

It seems, that Munkres also had the technical term *perfect map* in mind. Otherwise he wouldn't have written it in boldface style.

So, let's have a look at the definition of *[perfect map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_map)*:

> *Definition:* Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $p$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$ that is **continuous**, closed, surjective and such that $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact relative to $X$ for each $y$ in $Y$. Then $p$ is known as a **perfect map**.

We observe, that *continuity* is a necessary property of a *perfect map*. And the first example at this Wiki-page is

> If $p : X\rightarrow Y$ is a perfect map and $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact.

This does not imply, of course that continuity is necessary. For this example of perfect maps continuity is just a by-product. So, maybe Munkres has thought in terms of perfect maps and this was the reason to include continuity in his problem.