# Prove that if $Y$ is compact then $X$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

This is a prelim problem which I did not get correctly.

Let $p: X\to Y$ be a closed map. Suppose that $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for all $y\in Y$. Show that if $Y$ is compact then $X$ is compact.

In the prelim $p$ is not described as continuous so I assumed that it is not necessarily continuous. However I only get to the point where $p(X)$ is compact and I couldn't see how to use the assumption that $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for all $y$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @mathworker21 Your example does not satisfy $p^{-1}(\{0\})$ is compact. Moreover, your example $p$ *is* continuous.

Comment: When you say a closed map is it necessarily continuous? When I took the exam they did not give any correction to this problem.

Comment: @kccu stupid stupid me. thx

Comment: @JohnThompson No, a closed map need not be continuous. You should not assume $p$ is continuous.

Comment: @kccu Yeah that is also what I was thinking.

Comment: @JohnThompson Can you try to finish this off? 

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $X$ is not compact. We may thus take a net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ in $X$ with no convergent subnet. Then $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is a closed set in $X$, so $\{p(x_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is a closed set in $Y$. But since $Y$ is compact, it has a convergent subnet. So there is some $\gamma \in I$ and subnet $(\alpha_\beta)$ with $p(x_{\alpha_\beta}) \to p(x_\gamma)$. Now use that $p^{-1}(p(x_\gamma))$ is compact...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perfect Map $p:\ X\to Y$, $Y$ compact implies $X$ compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902472/perfect-map-p-x-to-y-y-compact-implies-x-compact) (Daniel Fischer's answer shows that continuity is not needed)

Comment: @mathworker21 nets can work but just covers is much simpler.